# How can I change to the dark mode?

Tags: sas, darkmode

How can I change to the dark mode in SAS9.4

All the videos I found are about prior versions of SAS and not this version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In SAS for Windows, you can edit the colour scheme.

For SAS Studio, you can download an extension, e.g. Dark Reader for Chrome.

Comment: Thank you for response. I am working on SAS for windows. Do I need to change the elements one by one in tools->options-> colors or there is another way to do so? thanks in advance